# Let's say that I observe "something" happen 3 out of 10 times. Is my reasoning here with regards to the prior probability correct?

Tags: probability

Let's say that I observe "something" happen 3 out of 10 times. I then conclude that the prior probability here is 0.3. This therefore means that the probability of a single "thing" occurring is 0.3 and the probability of the "thing" happening 3 out of 10 times is $0.3^3 = 0.027$. Is my reasoning here correct?

---

### EDIT

For a resolution to this question, see my comments to [Graham Kemp's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4552523/356308).

Comment: So by this logic, you flip a coin thrice and all three are heads. Then the “prior probability “ is $1$, so the probability of it happening 3 times in 3 trials is $1^3=1$ so every time you flip it in thr future, shouldn’t it fall heads ONLY?

Comment: @insipidintegrator You're right that that doesn't make sense. But read the example here https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/prior_probability.asp : "For example, three acres of land have the labels A, B, and C. One acre has reserves of oil below its surface, while the other two do not. The prior probability of oil being found on acre C is one third, or 0.333. But if a drilling test is conducted on acre B, and the results indicate that no oil is present at the location, then the posterior probability of oil being found on acres A and C become 0.5, as each acre has one out of two chances."

Comment: @insipidintegrator That is the same reasoning that I'm using in my example, is it not?

Comment: No, the “prior probability “, as I understand it, is the *theoretical* probability, i.e. without observation. There are three pieces of  land with equal area, so by theory, all factors equal, we have the probability of oil  being on any one is 1/3. The “posterior probability “, is the *empirical* probability.

Comment: Similar to Monty hall

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the sample space that the 'something' is being taken from?

Comment: @ewokx The point is that we have no idea. The only information we have is that, to put it simply, "out of 10, there are 3." That's why I'm trying to reason about this using the prior probability.

Comment: See also **"The Law of Large Numbers".**   With a key point being "ten is not that large a number".

Comment: @GrahamKemp Yes, I understand that.

Comment: @insipidintegrator In my case, the 3/10 was generated before any action was taken, so there is no conditional probability here like $P(A = 0.3 \mid B)$ (there is no $B$ in my case). That's why it seems to me like these are equivalent, and the prior probability is indeed 0.3.

Answer (score 1):

If the success rate for *any* single trial is exactly $3/10$, then you should evaluate the probability for three successes among ten *independent* trials to be:$$\binom {10}3\dfrac{3^3~7^7}{10^{10}} = 0.266827932$$

Comment: How do you reconcile this with the oil example? investopedia.com/terms/p/prior_probability.asp : "For example, three acres of land have the labels A, B, and C. One acre has reserves of oil below its surface, while the other two do not. The prior probability of oil being found on acre C is one third, or 0.333. But if a drilling test is conducted on acre B, and the results indicate that no oil is present at the location, then the posterior probability of oil being found on acres A and C become 0.5, as each acre has one out of two chances."

Comment: What is the difference between these two cases? I ask because I think the oil example is actually closer to my purpose, even though your reasoning here is, of course, correct.

Comment: Ahh, ok, I think I got it here https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/prior-probability: "The probability of outcome P(Y) is called prior probability, which can be calculated from the training dataset. Prior probability shows the likelihood of an outcome in a given dataset. For example, in the mortgage case, P(Y) is the default rate on a home mortgage, which is 2%. P(Y|X) is called the conditional probability, which provides the probability of an outcome given the evidence, that is, when the value of X is known."

Comment: In your case, you're describing a random/probabilistic process that actually *generates* outcomes, rather than something that already exists and "is what it is." Anyway, it seems that this clears things up.